# leaky listener firebase ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am trying to load message box data for chat functionality.

The message box is loaded as:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
          super.viewDidAppear(animated)

if (PFUser.currentUser()!["firebaseUID"] !== nil)
{
    print(PFUser.currentUser()!["firebaseUID"])
   self.updateResultArray(PFUser.currentUser()!["firebaseUID"] as! String)
}
}

    func updateResultArray(uid: String) {


    let userName = String(PFUser.currentUser()!["username"])

    //print("updateResultArray is getting called")
    let userhandle = self.firebase.childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(uid).childByAppendingPath("rooms").queryOrderedByValue()
        .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { roomsnapshot in

            let enumerator = roomsnapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FDataSnapshot {
                self.roomArray.append(rest.key)
            }

            //get the latest message from all the rooms
            if self.roomArray.isEmpty == false
            {
                for i in 0...self.roomArray.count-1
                {
                    print("in the room loop \(self.roomArray[i])")

                    let messagehandle = self.messagesRef.childByAppendingPath(self.roomArray[i]).queryOrderedByKey().queryLimitedToFirst(1).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {
                        messagesnapshot in

                        print("the messagesnapshot child count is \(messagesnapshot.childrenCount)")
                        let enumerator = messagesnapshot.children
                        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FDataSnapshot {

                            let sender = rest.value.objectForKey("sender") as? String
                            let reciever = rest.value.objectForKey("reciever") as? String

                            //print("sender is \(sender!) and reciever is \(reciever!)")


                            let eventhandle = self.firebase.childByAppendingPath("rooms").childByAppendingPath(self.roomArray[i]).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { eventsnapshot in

                                if eventsnapshot.value is  NSNull {
                                    // The value is null
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                let eventAttr = eventsnapshot.value.objectForKey("eventAttributes") as? String
                                let eventDetails = eventsnapshot.value.objectForKey("eventDetails") as? String


                                //print("userName is \(userName)")
                                //print("sender is \(sender)")
                                if (userName !=  sender!) //for event joinee
                                {
                                    let firstname1 = eventsnapshot.value.objectForKey("firstname1") as? String
                                    self.otherNames.append(sender!)
                                    self.resultsNameArray.append(firstname1!)
                                    self.base4String = eventsnapshot.value.objectForKey("img1") as! String
                                    self.resultsImageFiles.append(self.base4String)

                                }
                                else //for event creator
                                {
                                    let firstname2 = eventsnapshot.value.objectForKey("firstname2") as? String
                                    self.otherNames.append(reciever!)
                                    self.resultsNameArray.append(firstname2!)
                                    self.base4String = eventsnapshot.value.objectForKey("img2") as! String
                                    self.resultsImageFiles.append(self.base4String)

                                }

                                let newlineChars = NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()
                                let evntArray = eventDetails!.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(newlineChars).filter{!$0.isEmpty}
                                self.eventArray.append(evntArray[0])

                                self.eventdetailsArray.append(eventAttr!)

                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                                    self.resultsTable.reloadData()
                                }

                                }

                            })

                           // self.firebase.removeAuthEventObserverWithHandle(eventhandle)
                        }

                    })

                    //self.messagesRef.removeAuthEventObserverWithHandle(messagehandle)
                }

            }
        })


      //firebase.removeAuthEventObserverWithHandle(userhandle)


}
```

since i am using observeSingleEventOfType  i havent coded to remove handlers( i have tried that as well).

In the individual chat, the code is like this:

```
func refreshResults() {

    print("the roomid is \(roomid)")

    //update from firebase
   let messagehandle = self.messagesRef.childByAppendingPath(roomid).queryOrderedByKey()
        .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { messageTextsnapshot in

            self.messageArray.removeAll()
            self.senderArray.removeAll()


            //                print("the messageTextsnapshot child count is \(messageTextsnapshot.childrenCount)") // I got the expected number of items
            let enumerator = messageTextsnapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FDataSnapshot {


                let text = rest.value.objectForKey("message") as? String
                let sender = rest.value.objectForKey("sender") as? String


                if text != nil && text != ""
                {

                    self.messageArray.append(text!)
                    self.senderArray.append(sender!)

                }

            }


            for subView in self.resultsScrollView.subviews {
                subView.removeFromSuperview()
            }

            for var i = 0; i <= self.messageArray.count-1; i++ {


                if self.senderArray[i] == userName {


                    if (self.messageArray[i].rangeOfString(self.acceptMessage) != nil)
                    {

                        let chatBubbleData = ChatBubbleData(text: self.messageArray[i], image:self.myImg, date: NSDate(), type: .AcceptMine)

                        self.addChatBubble(chatBubbleData)

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        let chatBubbleData = ChatBubbleData(text: self.messageArray[i], image:self.myImg, date: NSDate(), type: .Mine)

                        self.addChatBubble(chatBubbleData)

                    }

                } else {

                    if (self.messageArray[i].rangeOfString(self.acceptMessage) != nil)
                    {

                        let chatBubbleData = ChatBubbleData(text: self.messageArray[i], image:self.otherImg, date: NSDate(), type: .Accept)

                        self.addChatBubble(chatBubbleData)

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        let chatBubbleData = ChatBubbleData(text: self.messageArray[i], image:self.otherImg, date: NSDate(), type: .Opponent)

                        self.addChatBubble(chatBubbleData)
                    }
                }

                let bottomOffset:CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, self.resultsScrollView.contentSize.height - self.resultsScrollView.bounds.size.height)
                self.resultsScrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: false)

            }


        })

    self.messagesRef.removeAuthEventObserverWithHandle(messagehandle)
}
```

There are a few other listeners similar to this. the problem is when i go back from this view(individual chat to message box, the memory consumption increases. I have cleared all arrays and closed the handlers immediately after use. but still memory consumption increases and sometimes in message box same rows are replicated again. how should i solve this. I tried using 
observeSingleEventOfType but it is not a correct solution as the data sync stops.

Used this as reference:
https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-15-best-practices-uiviewcontroller-ios-firebase.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i was closing the listeners on the parent and not on the child. so the listeners were still in memory.
When i closed the listeners on the full path it worked.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your message box object is not being released due to a retain cycle caused by the listener callback block holding a reference to the message box object.  You can alleviate this by using [weak self] in blocks that you pass to other objects.  For example:

```
            .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: 
                {
                    [weak self] roomsnapshot in

                    let enumerator = roomsnapshot.children
                    ...
```

This makes 'self' an optional type, and you can then add:

```
guard let strongSelf = self else { ... }
```

Comment: I'm using this method, but a problem I face is working with Bool. So, when a user sends a new chat message I set a bool so I can notify my update method that I do not want to remove a message & I am adding a new message. This works great on the current user, but if another user adds a new message my current user is not seeing it in the chat. Any suggestions?